# Show multiple free text compartments

Tags: rhapsody

I'm using Rational Rhapsody Architect for Systems Engineering to implement a domain-specific modeling language my team has designed. I'm building it as a profile that extends the SysML profile.

We have a metaclass that we've implemented as a new term stereotype applied to Class and generalized from Block.

I'd like to have multiple compartments with different names, that can display arbitrary text entered by the modeler in a Block Definition Diagram.

So far, only the Description compartment will display free text.

I can create an approximation by implementing a new term stereotype applied to Constraint. The specifications for those constraints are also free text and they appear in the diagram, but there are two problems: they are restricted to single line, and I can't seem to hide the stereotype name.

Do I have any options?